# NIFI: get value from json

Tags: minify, apache-nifi

i have a queryCassandra which generate json like this one:

```
{"results":[{"term":"term1"},{"term":"term2"}..]}
```

Now, i want to get from this all the term values separated by some separator in string format; ex :
term1,term2,term3

So i can pass this list as a string parameter for a java main program which i've alreat set.

(i only need the transofrmation, not the java program execution)

Thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily get those values by using following ways.

```
GetFile-->EvaluateJsonPath-->PutFile
```

In get file you have to specify location of json file.

In EvaluateJsonPath configure like following properties.,

```
Destination:flowfile-attribute
Return Type:json
input.term1:$.results.[0].term           //To get term
input.term2:$.results.[1].term
```

At the result of Evaluate json you have two attributes in which having those values.

**Result attributes:**

```
input.term1: term1

input.term2: term2
```

Above code works for me,so feel free to upvote/accept as answer.

Comment: Hi @uhb prab, thanks a lot for you answer, but the thing is that the number of terms i would receive from cassandra is unknown, so i can't do a static configuration in EvaluateJsonPath..

Comment: is there a processor so i can get an array of terms ex: [term1,term2] from a json array like this one: [{"term":"term1"},{"term:"term2"}]

Comment: Yes you can use SplitJson Processor after EvaluateJSON Path and give an JSONPathExpression like this:$.results.[*] for split the json values inside array.Here you can have two splits then use evaluatejsonPath to get values from two splits

Comment: @MisterX are you saying to EvaluateJSONPath then SplitJson then EvaluateJSONPath again?

Answer (score 1):

as a variant use ExecuteScript with groovy lang:

```java
import groovy.json.*

//get input file
def flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile)return

//parse json to map/array objects
def content = session.read(flowFile).withStream{ stream-> return new JsonSlurper().parse( stream ) }

//transform
content = content.results.collect{ it.term }.join(',')

//write new content
flowFile = session.write(flowFile,{ stream->
    stream << content.getBytes("UTF-8")
} as OutputStreamCallback)

session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```