# How to extract text from Json field

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I'm pretty new at Nifi and need help converting a Json response gotten from the InvokeHTTP processor.

The response that I receive is of the type :

```
{"key1": "value", "text": "This is an example of a text received.\nThis need to be parsed."}
```

I need to parse this response so that I end up with a file of the type :

```
This is an example of a text received.
This need to be parsed.
```

I've tried a few processors but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

This is what I got in entry [image: Input data]

And after configuring the EvaluateJsonPath processo like this[image: EvaluateJsonPath]

I still get the same file in return.[image: return file]

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112731/nifi-get-value-from-json

Comment: I've come across this post but it doesn't seem to work my way.

Comment: you have `Destination=flowfile-attribute`, so it's stored into attribute with name `text` rather then flowfile content

Comment: Wonderful !!! Thank you very much ;)